# Invalid verify on a non-virtual on an interface

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, nservicebus

The following code is raising and exception, MOQ is complaining about:

> "Invalid verify on a non-virtual"

but I am mocking an interface. I must have done these sort of tests a good few times but I'm not being able to figure what the issue is this time.

```
[TestFixture]
public class RegisterDeviceCommandHandlerTests
{
    private RegisterDeviceCommandHandler _handler;
    private readonly Mock<IClientRepository> _clientRepositoryMock = new Mock<IClientRepository>();
    private readonly Mock<IMessageHandlerContext>  _busMock = new Mock<IMessageHandlerContext>();
    private readonly Mock<IClientEncryptionProvider> _clientEncryptionProviderMock = new Mock<IClientEncryptionProvider>();


    [Test]
    public async Task GivenAnUnregisteredDeviceWhenTheDeviceIsAddedThenADeviceRegistrationCompletedEventShouldBePublished()
    {
        _clientRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.RegisterClient(It.IsAny<byte[]>(), It.IsAny<string>(),
                It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns(RegistrationClientOperationResult.Registered);

        var clientIdentity = new ClientIdentity
        {
            HostName = "HostName",
            MacAddress = "MacAddress",
            MachineId = "MachineId"
        };

        _clientEncryptionProviderMock.Setup(x => x.DecryptIdentity(It.IsAny<byte[]>())).Returns(clientIdentity);

        _handler = new RegisterDeviceCommandHandler(_clientEncryptionProviderMock.Object, _clientRepositoryMock.Object)
        {
            Bus = _busMock.Object
        };

        await _handler.HandleAsync(new RegisterDeviceCommand
        {
            Identity = new byte[] { 1, 2 }
        });

        _busMock.Verify(x => x.Publish(It.IsAny<DeviceRegistrationCompletedEvent>()));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking if `Publish` is an extension method and not actually a method on the interface?

Comment: @Nkosi you're right, I've just found it. That makes things I bit more complicated.

Comment: If you have an idea of what member the extension method is actually calling you can verify that, but that would be a good guess if you don't know the inner workings of the extension.

Answer (score 2):

Found it. [`IMessageHandlerContext`](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/blob/develop/src/NServiceBus.Core/IMessageHandlerContext.cs) inherits from [`IPipelineContext`](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/blob/develop/src/NServiceBus.Core/IPipelineContext.cs) which has a `Publish` method

```
/// <summary>
/// Publish the message to subscribers.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="message">The message to publish.</param>
/// <param name="options">The options for the publish.</param>
Task Publish(object message, PublishOptions options);
```

An [extension method](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/blob/develop/src/NServiceBus.Core/IPipelineContextExtensions.cs#L120) that takes one argument is available for the interface and that method.

```
/// <summary>
/// Publish the message to subscribers.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context">The instance of <see cref="IPipelineContext" /> to use for the action.</param>
/// <param name="message">The message to publish.</param>
public static Task Publish(this IPipelineContext context, object message)
{
    Guard.AgainstNull(nameof(context), context);
    Guard.AgainstNull(nameof(message), message);

    return context.Publish(message, new PublishOptions());
}
```

So to satisfy the extension method with the mock you would need to verify

```
_busMock.Verify(_ => _.Publish(It.IsAny<DeviceRegistrationCompletedEvent>(), Is.IsAny<PublishOptions>()));
```

Comment: @Marco, found the source code for the interface in question and suggested a workaround.

Comment: I ended up using their own Testing libraries. Thanks anyway :)